# quarterly S&P price

Tags: index, price

I need the quarterly S&P price, but only have the daily data. What is the official definition of the quarterly price? Is it just the average or is it the closing (opening) price of e.g. march closing price minus closing price december divided by closing december price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking at price returns, you would use:
(closing price of March - closing price of Dec) / closing price of Dec.
However, this would not include the returns due to dividends.  If you want total returns you would need to incorporate dividends.  Also, you would have to make some assumptions about the return on those dividends.  For example, are you assuming the dividends are re-invested into the S&P?  Or are you assuming the dividends are earning some money market rate.  Also, your return calculation would need to be explicit on the day count and compounding convention.